# I need help finding the correct input shape for my 2 dimensional CNN model

Tags: python, machine-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network, reshape

I am trying to build a CNN model for a 2d data. I have 1000 rows with 26 cols. this is the code I have, I have tried numerous combinations for my input shape but I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong.

```
# CNN
# The known number of output classes.
num_classes = 10

#  label encoding
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = encoder.fit_transform(y_test)

# one hot encoding
y_train = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.np_utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

# reshape 2D to 3D
x_train = X_train.reshape(670, 26, 1)
x_test = X_test.reshape(330, 26, 1)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

# build CNN model
model2 = models.Sequential()
model2.add(layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(26, 1), activation='relu'))  # convolution
model2.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))  # pooling
model2.add(layers.Flatten())  # flatten
model2.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))  # fc
2.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# model compile
model2.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
               optimizer=adam,
               metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()
batch_size = 128
epochs = 5000
model = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                  batch_size=batch_size,
                  epochs=epochs,
                  verbose=2,
                  callbacks=early_stopping,
                  validation_split=0.1,
                  )
```

This gives:

```
Error:ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: expected axis -1 of input shape to have value 26 but received input with shape (None, 26, 1)
```

Comment: can you post your dataset link? training and testing dateset should have the same shape

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1X4M3BHp0QGeV63uFvSL1TWyOGhQvcq1P/view?usp=sharing   this is the link to the data

Comment: I think that you forgot something in question. Because this code should work fine with the data shape you have mentioned.

Comment: If you sure that this code with the mentioned data shape and type throws error, then check if you imported all libraries  from `tensorflow.keras.*` and not from `keras.*`. By the way it is better to change this line: `encoder.fit_transform(y_test)`  to `encoder.transform(y_test)`.

Comment: Is CNN good fit in this use case? In CNN, convolutional kernels tries to capture the local spatial correlation. Your data is numerical in nature.Is the distance between two columns in your data meaningful? If not, you may not get good prediction with CNN here.

Answer (score 1):

Your implementation would work perfectly if you load the data correctly and fit the label encoder on Train only, then transform Train & Test set!

```
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv')
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.33)
y_train, X_train = train.iloc[:,-1].values, train.iloc[:,1:-1].values
y_test, X_test = test.iloc[:,-1].values, test.iloc[:,1:-1].values
print(X_test.shape, X_train.shape, y_test.shape, y_train.shape)

# CNN
# The known number of output classes.
num_classes = 10

#  label encoding
encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = encoder.fit_transform(y_train)
y_test = encoder.transform(y_test)

# one hot encoding
y_train = to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)

# reshape 2D to 3D
x_train = X_train.reshape(670, 26, 1)
x_test = X_test.reshape(330, 26, 1)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)

# build CNN model
model2 = models.Sequential()
model2.add(layers.Conv1D(64, kernel_size=2, input_shape=(26, 1), activation='relu'))  # convolution
model2.add(layers.MaxPool1D(pool_size=2))  # pooling
model2.add(layers.Flatten())  # flatten
model2.add(layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'))  # fc
model2.add(layers.Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax'))

# model compile
model2.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy",
               optimizer=Adam(),
               metrics=['accuracy'])

# model.summary()
batch_size = 128
epochs = 5000
model = model2.fit(x_train, y_train,
                  batch_size=batch_size,
                  epochs=epochs,
                  verbose=2,
                  callbacks=EarlyStopping(),
                  validation_split=0.1,
                  )
```

output:

```
(330, 26) (670, 26) (330,) (670,)
(670, 26)
(330, 26)
(670, 26, 1)
(330, 26, 1)
Epoch 1/5000
5/5 - 0s - loss: 244.5596 - accuracy: 0.0829 - val_loss: 151.6749 - val_accuracy: 0.1045
```